# how to disable Umi UI bubble in Ant Design Pro?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd, ant-design-pro, umijs

I am new with Ant Design Pro, I get project from git repo of Ant Design and I want to disable/hide Umi UI bubble on display. I refered to many pages and Google but It did not work for me. It taught me that created an `.env` and added line of code `UMI_UI=none umi dev`.

**My problem is described with below picture**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change package.json "start": "cross-env UMI_UI=none umi dev"

Comment: I have an opposite question, how can I enable this bubble? I'm using Ant Design Pro in my project, but I don't see this bubble. Do you have any clue?

Comment: It seems the when I fetch all blocks enable the bubble but when the empty template is setup, the bubble seems to be missing

Comment: @jupiteror I'm running with the same issue, did you solve this? I'm running the app in dev mode, and I've tried a new project of v4 & v5, full setup, and minimal setup

Comment: @HTMHell I think I just have installed `@umijs/preset-ui`.

Answer (score 2):

It is only run when you're running the app in dev mode. It is not included in the production build, therefore it won't be an issue. You can use it for various quick actions like fetching blocks, templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `UMI_UI=none npm start`

Comment: I tried with your guide but it still doesn't work for me....